# Exporting several tibbles to separate sheets in excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel, tibble, r-xlsx

I'm looking for a way to automate some data clean-up. So far, I've figured out how to import several excel workbooks and all their sheets into R using the following:

```
my_data = expand_grid(
    file = list.files("~path", full.names = TRUE),
     sheet = seq(6)
 ) %>%
     transmute(data = file %>% map2(sheet, ~ read_excel(path = .x, sheet = .y, skip = 2))) %>%
     pull(data)
```

What I need help with is exporting all of the resulting tibbles into an Excel workbook, one tibble per sheet.

I'm using the following method to try to print (based on a previously answered question):

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tibble)
output_expediter <- function(df, output_filename) {
     nm1 <- deparse(substitute(df))
     wb <- createWorkbook()
     addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = nm1)
     writeData(wb, sheet= nm1, x = df)
     saveWorkbook(wb =wb, file = output_filename, overwrite = TRUE)
     }
```

I get the following error:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 52, 8, 0, 5

It is true that all the tibbles differ in row numbers.I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```r
library(purrr)

my_data <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx") |>
  set_names() |>
  map(rio::import_list)
  
iwalk(my_data, ~ writexl::write_xlsx(.x, .y))
```

**How it works**

1. We use `set_names` which gives a named vector, where the names and values (for the moment) are the file path to the workbooks.

```r
  wb1.xlsx   wb2.xlsx 
"wb1.xlsx" "wb2.xlsx"
```

2. We iterate over this named list using `map` and to each element we apply `rio::import_list`. This will import all sheets of a workbook, preserving the sheet names. By doing this, we have preserved *both* the workbook path AND the worksheet names:

```
map(my_data, \(x) map(x, \(y) head(y, 1)))

$wb1.xlsx
$wb1.xlsx$a
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

$wb1.xlsx$b
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

$wb1.xlsx$c
            name height mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year  sex
1 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue         19 male
     gender homeworld species films vehicles starships
1 masculine  Tatooine   Human    NA       NA        NA


$wb2.xlsx
$wb2.xlsx$c
            name height mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year  sex
1 Luke Skywalker    172   77      blond       fair      blue         19 male
     gender homeworld species films vehicles starships
1 masculine  Tatooine   Human    NA       NA        NA

$wb2.xlsx$b
  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

$wb2.xlsx$a
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

3. Lastly we iterate over each workbook name and write all the data frames to sheets within a workbook. By default `writexl::write_xlsx` will use the list names as sheet names.

**Data**

I created some fake workbooks in my current working directory:

```r
l1 <- list(iris, mtcars, dplyr::starwars)
names(l1) <- letters[seq(length(l1))]
l2 <- rev(l1)

writexl::write_xlsx(l1, "wb1.xlsx")
writexl::write_xlsx(l2, "wb2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm still running into a problem.

my_data <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx") |>
  set_names()

Works just fine.

map(rio::import_list)
Is giving me the following error:
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
With name: ~filename.xlsx
Caused by error:
! `path` does not exist: ~filename.xlsx

Comment: The code I have posted likely needs to be adjusted for your file system. As I mentioned, I created these workbooks in my *current working directory*. You should specify the `path` argument of `list.files` to point to the location where your workbooks exist.

Comment: I did specify path within it like so:
my_data <- list.files(path = "~path", pattern = ".xlsx")|>
  set_names() |>
  map(rio::import_list)

Is there somewhere else I should be doing it? Sorry for all the questions, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Can shoe me the output of `list.files(path = "~path", pattern = ".xlsx")|> set_names()`? (Without the `map(rio::import_list)`).

Comment: ```> my_data
    Application Support Analyst_Canada_Job Post.xlsx   Application Support Analyst_Montreal_Job Post.xlsx 
  "Application Support Analyst_Canada_Job Post.xlsx" "Application Support Analyst_Montreal_Job Post.xlsx" 
   Application Support Analyst_Toronto_Job Post.xlsx 
 "Application Support Analyst_Toronto_Job Post.xlsx" ```

It does grab each file name.

Comment: Ah those are just file names so it is looking in your current working directory for them. You should probably specify `list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)`